# What does bien mean in this context

Tags: grammaire, sens

*Bien* means well or good. But in "la condition de l'énoncé est bien nécessaire", *bien* appears to mean *also*. So I wonder what is the exact meaning of *bien* here.

Comment: English "well" can also be used in a similar way for emphasis, but the usage is generally more restricted than in French and may appear old-fashioned.

Comment: @xngtng I think this is more common in British English than in American English. It's not quite an authoritative source, but The Street's album _Original Pirate Material_ has a couple of usages like this, ex,
"But I get well leery when geezers look at me funny"

and

"Buy a drink, chat to a lady, the girl's well fit"

Comment: @svangordon: That is true but it is a colloquial usage; you'd be unlikely to see it in formal writing.

Comment: @psmears More formal expression also exist - *"The flight dynamics of bees are well understood"*, etc.

Comment: @J... Right, but that is grammatically different: there the adverb *well* is qualifying a verb (in participle form), which is standard English on both sides of the Atlantic; qualifying an adjective it is much more restricted.

Comment: @psmears Yes, grammatically different, but nevertheless carrying a very similar meaning.  Agreed with adjectives it's chiefly informal BrE, but also very much so in some French also (ie: Quebecois - *"Mes bottes y'sont ben (bien) maganées"*, etc).

Comment: @psmears I think what we're talking about is the adverb form of the word; Wiktionary thinks that only the meaning of "Very" as a general purpose intensifier is BrE slang (ex, "It was well good"). In the sense of "To a significant degree" it can still be formal: "They were well capable of adapting", "I am beating a horse now already well dead"

Comment: @svangordon: Yes, indeed, that is a different meaning :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this sentence, « bien » means “indeed”.

Comment: It does indeed :-)

Comment: Bien sûr, mon ami!

Answer (score 2):

'Indeed' or 'certainly'

It is the reinforcement of the word it precedes.
In the case of a steak 'bien cuit' is well done or well cooked.

Comment: Sounds almost completely analogous to how English people use the word 'well'. 'That's well tasty!' (Americans don't use this often I don't think, apart from a couple examples like "well done")

Comment: Using 'well tasty', 'well hard' etc. is grammatically incorrect and only slang usage (which is fine, but hopefully you wouldn't be using it in a job interview for example - unless you wanted to demonstrate street cred.)                                                                                   'Bien' - is however proper usage when applied as said. The meaning is different though.

Comment: Well is the adjectival equivalent of good in English.                                                                                                      'Well done' as a commendation or as a description of how your meat has been cooked is also correct usage. It appears to be that you can apply the adjective to a verb ut not to another adjective. Hopefully that is well explained.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sur "bien" in your sentence is a shortened usage of "bel et bien" which means indeed also